# Select all from array where key: name is equal something

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have got array of `var players = []` that holds info like `userID`, `userScore` etc.. usually I would select specific player by doing something like `players[i]` where i is a number position in array. But for one bit of my application I do not know this number, but I do know `userID` And I'm trying to figure out how to update `userScore` in `players` array where `userID` is equal to something, lets say `abc_123`

Comment: Loop over the array and stop when you find a match.

Comment: Wouldn't an object be a better way to store this information than an array?

Comment: @RocketHazmat That was my initial thought, but is there really no way to select items from it knowing one of the key values?

Comment: You could also use the built in indexOf: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Each array item is a javascript object?

Comment: @LcSalazar yes it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.

```
var findId = 'jkl';
var theGoose = players.filter(function(user){ return user.userId === findId; }).pop();
```

```js
var players = [
{
  userId: 'abc',
  userInfo: 'duck'
},
{
  userId: 'def',
  userInfo: 'duck'
},
{
  userId: 'ghi',
  userInfo: 'duck'
},
{
  userId: 'jkl',
  userInfo: 'goose!'
},
{
  userId: 'mno',
  userInfo: 'duck'
}];

var findId = 'jkl';
var theGoose = players.filter(function(user){ return user.userId === findId; }).pop();
$('#debug').text( theGoose.userInfo );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="debug"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(var i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
    if(players[i].userId === 'someId'){
        //doSomething(player[i]);
        players[i].userScore = 'abc_123';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method:

```
var players = [ { userId: 123 } ];
var user = players.find(function(item) {
    return item.userId === 123;
});

if (user != null) {
    // user is the first element in the players array that
    // satisfied the desired condition (a.k.a user.userId === 123)
}
```

Comment: Worth to note that the Array.find method is `Experimental` and not part of the ECMA5 standard.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the array items are objects, you can use the filter function:

```
var player = players.filter(function(p)
{
    return p.userID == "something";
}).forEach(function(p) {
    p.userScore = "something";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a Dictionary rather than an array.  The key can naturally be the player ID.  The rest of the information can be put in some object type. Then you can easily access the Dictionary by key.

Answer (score 0):

Try with grep:

```
var players = [
    {score: 10,userId: 1},
    {score: 20,userId: 2},
    {score: 30,userId: 3}
];


function findByUsrId(id){
    return $.grep(players, function(item){
      return item.userId == id;
    });
};

console.log(findByUsrId(2));
```

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pfbwq98k/